# Python GUI for portable app

Tags: python, user-interface, portable-applications

I am developing a python app, using python and sqlite and GUI to re-create a Access 2007 report generating app. Since the app is portable, I'm looking for GUI solution for python that user doesn't need to install addition things before using the app.

Is there any GUI solution suits my need? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) is very portable

Comment: So are tkinter, PyGTK and PyQt.

Comment: Yes, but wxPython is also fun. ;)

Comment: wxPython cannot be installed via the Fink package manager on Mac OS X, I believe because of technical issues: wxPython is currently less portable than PyQt.

Comment: So is easygui, which is simpler to use and allows access to tkinter if you would still like to use that

Answer (score 9):

The only fully portable GUI for Python is the standard **TkInter**, if you don't want any additional install beside Python.  The [Themed Tk](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html) version is quite nice looking, compared to the older Tk version (the themed version is available through the `ttk` module).

A few weeks ago, I had to answer the same question as you.  I came to the conclusion that **PyQt** is currently the best choice for a modern, powerful, well-maintained, and portable GUI, mainly because of some of the shortcomings of its main contender (wxPython, see below).  (Tk, and Themed Tk would be good for simpler needs.)

Two words of warning against **wxPython**: it is not possible to install it via the popular Fink package manager on Mac OS X, currently, which makes it far less portable than PyQt and TkInter; it is also not yet Python 3-compatible, as far as I know.

**PS** (Dec. 2012): [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) is currently a strong alternative to PyQt. There are a few Stackoverflow questions about the respective merits of these two Python bindings.

Comment: standard doesn't mean what it used to mean, in this case.  tkinter is present by default in the official, mainline standard library.  However, a number of common linux distributions (notably Ubuntu), slice that library up and only install it if the user asks for it or something that is dependent on it.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Interesting info.  Thank you for sharing!